# Geospatial Indexing "No mapping found for field" with YAML

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, yaml, geospatial, embedded-database

I have a problem trying to map an embedded document for geospatial indexing using Doctrine2's OD with YAML format, and MongoDB :
I would try to embed a "Coordinate" Document in the "Place" document to be able to execute some geospatial indexed queries, but got a mapping problem.

As seen on the official documentation :
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/indexes.html#geospatial-indexing

But I work with YAML mapping format...
And got this problem :

"No mapping found for field '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/intramuros-web/src/IntraMuros/CoreBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Coordinates.mongodb.yml' in class 'IntraMuros\CoreBundle\Document\Coordinates'."

Here's my YAML file : Place.mongodb.yml, correctly placed in Resources\config directory of my Symfony2's bundle.

```
IntraMuros\CoreBundle\Document\Place:
  type: document
  db: intramuros
  collection: places
  repositoryClass: IntraMuros\CoreBundle\Repository\PlaceRepository
  fields:
    id:
      type: id
      id:  true
    name:
      type: string
    address:
      type: string
    coordinates:
      embedded: true
      type: one
      targetDocument: IntraMuros\CoreBundle\Document\Coordinates
      cascade: all
      strategy: set
    indexes:
      coordinates:
        keys:
          coordinates: 2d

IntraMuros\CoreBundle\Document\Coordinates:
  type: EmbeddedDocument
  db: intramuros
  fields:
    latitude:
      type: float
    longitude:
      type: float
```

And Here's the PHP Document class I would to use.

```
<?php

namespace IntraMuros\CoreBundle\Document;


/**
 * @Document(requireIndexes=true)
 * @Indexes({
 *     @Index(keys={"coordinates"="2d"})
 * })
 */
class Place
{
    /**
     * @Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @String
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @String 
     */
    protected $address;

    /**
     * @EmbedOne(targetDocument="IntraMuros\CoreBundle\Document\Coordinates")
     */
    protected $coordinates;

    public function __construct($latitude = NULL, $longitude = NULL)
    {
        $coordinates = new Coordinates($latitude, $longitude);
        $this->setCoordinates($coordinates);
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;
    }

    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setCoordinates($coordinates)
    {
        $this->coordinates = $coordinates;
    }

    public function getCoordinates($toArray = false)
    {
        if ($toArray) {
            if ($this->coordinates) {
                return $this->coordinates->toArray();
            }
        }
        return $this->coordinates;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => $this->getId(),
            'name' => $this->getName(),
            'address' => $this->getAddress(),
            'coordinates' => $this->getCoordinates(true)
        );
    }
}


/**
 * @EmbeddedDocument
 */
class Coordinates
{
    /**
     * @Float
     */
    protected $latitude;

    /**
     * @Float
     */
    protected $longitude;

    public function __construct($latitude = NULL, $longitude = NULL)
    {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;
        $this->longitude = $longitude;
    }

    public function setLatitude($latitude)
    {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;
    }

    public function getLatitude()
    {
        return $this->latitude;
    }

    public function setLongitude($longitude)
    {
        $this->longitude = $longitude;
    }

    public function getLongitude()
    {
        return $this->longitude;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return array(
            'latitude' => $this->getLatitude(),
            'longitude' => $this->getLongitude()
        );
    }
}
```

Thank you a lot in advance,
Bobby.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use annotations instead of YML for mapping your documents.

It will work very easily.

Good luck ! ;)

Comment: Oooohh yes it works perfectly !!
Damn, I'll never forget this good practice to use @Annotations for database entities/documents mapping !!!

Comment: I don't think that this is really that constructive an answer.  ODM offers YML mapping, so 'using another way' doesn't help those needing to use YAML notation (due to not wanting to contaminate the domain object with implementation details)