# How to map mongo documents with subdocuments in symfony2

Tags: mongodb, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create symfony2 application which will access mongoDB collection with the following structure:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5239c1c0359bf908058a5071"),
  "param2": "test",
  "param3": {
       "subparam31": 0,
       "subparam32": 0,
       "subparam33": 0
   },
   "param4": 1
}
```

In symfony 2 I create a .yml, and php class. I correctly map only "_id", "param2" and "param4", but not "subparam31", "subparam32" and "subparam33" of "param3".

I use next file structure for mapping:

Params.mongodb.yml:

```
Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Params:
db: test 
type: document
fields:
    id:
        id:  true
    param2:
        type: string
    param3:
        type: mixed
    subparam31:
        type: float
    subparam32:
        type: float
    subparam33:
        type: float
    param4:
        type: float
```

Params.php

```
<?php
 namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Document;

class Params 
{
    protected $param2; 

    protected $param4;

    protected $param3;

    protected $subparam31;  

    protected $subparam32; 

    protected $subparam33;
}
?>
```

Where I'm wrong? How to get and set values of subparams?

For accessing param2, param4 and id I use following code in controller which works:

```
$parameter = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
        ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Params')
        ->find($id);
    $parameter2 = $parameter->getParam2();
    $parameter4 = $parameter->getParam4();
    if (!$format) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Not found parameter with id -> '.$id);
    }
    return array(
    "parameter2" => $parameter2,
    "parameter4" => $parameter4
    );
```

I hope I was clear enough.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution! In addition to mapping in yml, appropriate annotation in php classes also should be defined.

Here is the content the necessary files:

Params.mongodb.yml

```
Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Params:
db: test 
type: document
embedOne:
    param3: 
        targetDocument: Param3
fields:
    id:
        id:  true
    param2:
        type: string
    param4:
        type: float
```

Param3.mongodb.yml

```
Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Param3:
db: test 
type: embeddedDocument
fields:
    subparam31:
        type: float
    subparam32:
        type: float
    subparam33:
        type: float
```

Params.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations;

/**
 * @Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Document
 */
class Params
{
/**
 * @Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Id
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\String
 */
protected $param2;

/**
 * @Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Float
 */
protected $param4;

/**
 * @Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\EmbedOne(targetDocument="Param3")
 */
protected $param3;

public function __construct($subparam31 = NULL, $subparam32 = NULL, $subparam33 = NULL)
{
    $param3 = new Param3($subparam31, $subparam32, $subparam33); 
    $this->setParam3($param3);
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return id $id
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set param2
 *
 * @param string $param2
 * @return self
 */
public function setParam2($param2)
{
    $this->param2 = $param2;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get param2
 *
 * @return string $param2
 */
public function getParam2()
{
    return $this->param2;
}

/**
 * Set param4
 *
 * @param float $param4
 * @return self
 */
public function setParam4($param4)
{
    $this->param4 = $param4;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get param4
 *
 * @return float $param4
 */
public function getParam4()
{
    return $this->param4;
}

/**
 * Set param3
 *
 * @param Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Param3 $param3
 * @return self
 */
public function setParam3(\Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Param3 $param3)
{
    $this->param3 = $param3;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get param3
 *
 * @return Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Param3 $param3
 */

public function getParam3($toArray = false)
{
    if ($toArray) {
        if ($this->param3) {
            return $this->param3->toArray();
        }
    }
    return $this->param3;
}
public function toArray()
{
    return array(
        'param3' => $this->getParam3(true)
    );
}
```

}

Param3.php

```
<?php

 namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Document;

 use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations;

 /**
  * @Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\EmbeddedDocument
  */
 class Param3
 {
/**
 * @Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Float
 */
protected $subparam31;

/**
 * @Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Float
 */
protected $subparam32;

/**
 * @Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Float
 */
protected $subparam33; 

public function __construct($subparam31 = NULL, $subparam32 = NULL, $subparam33 = NULL)
{
    $this->subparam31 = $subparam31;
    $this->subparam32 = $subparam32;
$this->subparam33 = $subparam33; 
}


/**
 * Set subparam31
 *
 * @param float $subparam31
 * @return self
 */
public function setSubparam31($subparam31)
{
    $this->subparam31 = $subparam31;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get subparam31
 *
 * @return float $subparam31
 */
public function getSubparam31()
{
    return $this->subparam31;
}

/**
 * Set subparam32
 *
 * @param float $subparam32
 * @return self
 */
public function setSubparam32($subparam32)
{
    $this->subparam32 = $subparam32;
    return $subparam32;
}

/**
 * Get subparam32
 *
 * @return float $subparam32
 */
public function getSubparam32()
{
    return $this->subparam32;
}

/**
 * Set subparam33
 *
 * @param float $subparam33
 * @return self
 */
public function setSubparam33($subparam33)
{
    $this->subparam33 = $subparam33;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get subparam33
 *
 * @return float $subparam33
 */
public function getSubparam33()
{
    return $this->subparam33;
}

public function toArray()
{
    return array(
        'subparam31' => $this->getSubparam3(),
        'subparam32' => $this->getSubparam32(),
    'subparam33' => $this->getSubparam33()
    );
}
```

}

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065595/geospatial-indexing-no-mapping-found-for-field-with-yaml) helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is an [EmbeddedDocument](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/embedded-mapping.html).

Define a separate document for `param3` (that includes subparam31, subparam32, and subparam33) set it as the targetDocument in params. So `Params.mongodb.yml` would look something like:

```
db: test 
type: document
embedOne:
  params3:
     targetDocument: params3Class
fields:
    id:
        id:  true
    param2:
        type: string
    param4:
        type: float
```

Comment: OK, how I can then access subparam31, subparam32 and subparam33 from controller in symfony and get and set their values? I can access id, param2 and param4, but not the others. What code I should write?

Comment: You would just write a getter method for params that gives you access to params3. So it could look like this: `$subparams31 = $params->getParams3()->getSubParam31()`

Comment: Getter method not works, I do not know why. When I use it in the way you suggested, I get a white screen in browser.

Comment: It's probably because function $getParam3() does not return an object, but the variable. For generating php classes, the following command was used: php app/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents AcmeStoreBundle. Maybe symfony does not perform the appropriate mapping.

Comment: Did you define a class that represents the params3 sub-document like in the example in the Doctrine documentation?